# How to display child categories a filter

Tags: magento-1.9, php, filter

I currently have a shop by filter that displays parent category and sub category, I would like to add a child category as a drop down to the sub, please have a look at the link of what I currently have http://yaubrothers.xist2test.com/index.php/products.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily by adding a subcategory under your MC2. 
Manage Categories - Select Your Subcat (example RICE), then add subcategory by selecting RICE.

Regards,
Mohsin

Answer (score -1):

I have done this, the sub category is appearing under the parent category I want to display the child category of the sub category. Hope that make sense.

Comment: Is this an answer or additional information to the question? If it's an answer, please explain so that others will understand. If not, don't add it as an answer, you can edit your question instead.